# Debug multithread Java application

Tags: java, debugging, concurrency

I have a method in class which is extended by other classes. Inherited classes call a method in separated threads. This method is implemented in parent class (it is the same for every inherited class). Can I debug this method somehow? I use IntelliJ IDEA.

I have this call in my main method.

```
    for (GenericProcessLoop loop : loops) {
        loop.loopThread();
    }
```

And that how "loopThread()" looks like.

```
    public void loopThread() {
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               loop();
           }
        });
    }
```

"loop()" here is the method in base class. I can't post it here due to privacy rules. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *"Can I debug this method somehow?"* Yes, put a [**breakpoint**](https://www.google.com/search?q=intellij+breakpoint) in the method.

Comment: Doesn't work this way, it is just skipped, from line "executor.submit()" to the last line of "loopThread()". Doesn't matter whether i have breakpoint in "loop()" or not

Comment: Of course, the submitting thread will continue without stopping at a break point placed in the asynchronous action. But the thread actually executing the action will stop there. If the executor ever runs the code of the action.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint and in the debugger section you will have frames and threads tab.

Comment: I do have it, but I can't enter the method. It is just skipped.

Comment: Okay,  I found it, I just needed to choose another thread in "Frames" window, and I can go throw this method. Thanks